# What's the best approach for results of a running race?

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization

I am a student in a good statistics program, but I'm not always the best at picking the tools/process to apply to a problem. To be clear, this is NOT homework, I am asking for a project that I have in mind for myself.

Let's say there is a runner in 5K races. The runner has data on their placing in the event in relation to the population of runners in the race. So they know they finished in X place out of N runners. The data would look like:

```
Placing   Field of Runners
10          120
2           135
23          131   
560         810
1           10
```

Now the runner wants to answer - "I am running in a race with 118 people today, what is my likely placing in the race?". The runner would be interested in either a placing or a percentage placing in the field, like the top 5%, the top 10%, etc. Like, "what is my likelihood of placing in the top 10% of the field today?".

At first I thought of doing something with a normal distribution and a z-score. But I'm not sure if that would make sense because of the disparity in the size of the fields; some fields may have 10 runners, other times it will have thousands.

Then I was thinking about normalizing the data with a percentage placing - like top 12%, top 80%, etc - but then I'm a little hazy on how to go on from there.

Or maybe it's a linear regression issue???

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If you truly are trying to address a realistic question, then it cannot be done with any accuracy using such limited types of data.  Different races attract different runners and will be more or less competitive. For instance, in the fourth race your hypothetical runner did not even place in the first half of an extremely large field, even though they were in the top 8% in every other race. Before you ask about statistical *procedures* you need to construct a useful *conceptual model* of what you are studying.

Comment: @whuber the data is what it is, my friend :). What you're describing could be more of a data normalization issue or maybe there needs to be different categories for the data, like race with more than 500 runners are a separate effort. Again, I cited this as a core issue - can z-scores work with disparate fields (and the disparate results that may come with them?)

Comment: It's not a "normalization issue," despite appearances.  But if this is all the information you've got, then you have to live with its limitations. That suggests, though, that you not try too hard to obtain good predictions, since that will be possible only by adopting unconfirmable assumptions and any results will likely contain some unknown amount of bias which we can *expect* to be present but which cannot be measured.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the distribution of your place in the race. It's normal, see [this note](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~dstephens/OldCourses/556-2006/Math556-Median.pdf).

So, the simplest estimator is to get the percentiles from your data set for each race and average them. That would be your estimate of your place in the next race. You can weight the ranks by $\sqrt{n_i}$, where $n_i$ is the number of runners in races, this will wight the big races heavier.

Here's MATLAB example for both simple and weighted means, and your place in next race with 100 runners:

```
a=[10          120
2           135
23          131   
560         810
1           10]

% unweighted mean
m = mean(a(:,1)./a(:,2))

%wighted mean

mw = mean((a(:,1)./a(:,2) .* sqrt(a(:,2))) / sum (sqrt(a(:,2))))

% place in 100 runners race

round(mw*100,0)
```

Output:

```
m =

   0.213015738384695


mw =

   0.070342921102228


ans =

     7
```

This is assuming that you got to popular 5K races with significant number of runners, hundreds. In small races it's hard to argue that the runners would be similar race to race. In big races such as Kormen's pink run, the runners body doesn't change much.

Comment: A Normal approximation is not necessarily applicable. In the example, the distribution in the race with just ten runners definitely is not anywhere close to Normal. Of great concern is the likelihood that the correct place varies from one race to another: this means that the sampling distributions of the quantiles can be expected to account only for a part of the variation in results. You *definitely* don't want to use a straight average of percentiles, because their sampling distributions all have (quite) different variances.

Comment: @whuber, to apply CLT we usually want the sample size over 30, so 10 runner race is too small, of course. That's why I mentioned the popular races. In my area even the county-level races attract hundreds of people.

Comment: Note that because this is a stats site, rather than a running site, we have to treat this as a question about making a prediction from the kinds of data that have been presented. That obliges us to take seriously the example with the value (1,10). Regardless, the recommendation to take a straight average is not a good one, given the variation in variances. The (560,810) datum is far more precise than the (1,10) datum--by a factor of more than $34$.

Comment: @whuber, OP can weight by $\sqrt{n}$, it'll be a better estimator, perhaps.

Comment: That won't work very well, either.  Instead of guessing what might work, it would be more helpful to construct and describe a probability model and propose an admissible estimator for that model. Why not look at a generalized linear mixed model in the Binomial family?